# Convert elements in a list from string to an int

Tags: c#, .net, string, data-structures

I am reading in integer data from a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

```
40  50  60  70  80
```

I may be doing this all wrong (and that's why I am asking) but I am reading the data as a string and then splitting on the tab so I can create an array and access the elements to do further computation, but I end up having to convert back to an int `(int x = Int32.Parse(next);)` to do any operations.  I know enough to know this whole thing seems very inefficient.  Any suggestions to stream line things here a bit?

```
StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(@"TestData.txt");
{
    while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(stRead.ReadLine());
    }

    string test = (string)listBox1.Items[5];

    string[] words = test.Split('\t');

    string next = words[2];
    int x = Int32.Parse(next);

    int y = x * x;
}
```

Comment: Does it really worth the trouble of optimizing it? Do you have a million or more lines? If so, use async to distribute the work between threads.

Comment: Any specific reason you need the ListBox ?

Comment: the data that I am dealing with has about 10 columns and a few hundred rows.  It doesn't need to be a listbox, I am just brain storming and open to suggestions

Comment: A `ListBox` is a UI element. It's best to avoid mixing data operation with UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no real performance improvement that you could do, but you may be able to get rid of some unnecessary local variables.

Eg:

```
List<int> intList = ((string)listBox1.Items[5]).Split('\t').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

If you really don't need a ListBox, a DataTable is another option to handle such big amount of data. You could create required amount of columns with Int32 type.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
dt.Columns.AddRange(lines.First().Split('\t').Select(col => new DataColumn(){DataType = typeof(Int32)}).ToArray());
lines.Select(x => x.Split('\t')).ToList().ForEach(row => dt.Rows.Add(row));
```

Comment: Your example may work in principle, but misses out on the multiple lines the file has as well as the (weird) thing that only `Items[5]` of the `ListBox` content is being considered.

Comment: Wouldn't introducing the overhead of expression trees involved in Select be significantly slower? The fact that you made it one line doesn't help performance if you use less performing code.

Comment: it is just an example, in the end I will need to loops through the all of the elements in all of the rows to perform operations

Comment: @dman2306 - There's no expression tree here. It's purely LINQ-to-Objects so it's plain `IEnumerable<T>` code, not `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @eltel2910: That's correct, this is just an example. Hope you can utilize it as per your requirement. Note that it's not very good to use a UI control as a data structure if you really don't want to show it on UI.

Answer (score 1):

This might be better:

```
int y =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"TestData.txt")
        .Skip(5)
        .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Split('\t')[2]))
        .Select(x => x * x)
        .First();
```

But I suspect that you need it to be more robust. Do let us know what the actual data structure is.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use  `ForEach`, I have changed your initial code just to illustrate the concept

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();
str.Split('\t').ToList().ForEach(i =>
               values.Add(Int32.Parse(i)));
```

Comment: How is making a list of strings by calling ToList then converting to a list of ints faster?

Comment: @dman2306 it does not... But it lets one to use `List<T>.ForEach`, (which I find somewhat questionable for task at hand, but it demonstrates useful technique if one dislikes `Enumerable.Aggregate`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select` method with function parameter passed to it.

```
var str = "40\t50\t60\t70\t80";
var ints = str.Split('\t').ToList().Select(int.Parse);
```